# Flutter: drawer becomes unavailable when pushing subviews with Navigator

Tags: flutter

Link to source on github: https://github.com/dnn1s/flutter_navigationtest

I want to accomplish the same navigation approach as Google does with the Play Store app: the drawer lists the available "root" views (in my case, view1 to view3), while any root view can have any number of subviews and its own navigation stack. The catch is: even when the user is on one of the subviews, the drawer is still accessible by using a swipe gesture, starting from the outer left of screen and going to the center - and this is not possible with my current approach. As for the Play Store app, when you tap on an app to see its details, you can either go back by tapping the arrow on the upper left OR directly invoke the drawer by swiping.

**main.dart:** nothing fancy

```
void main() => runApp(new NavigationTestApp());

class NavigationTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Navigation test',
            home: new MainPage(),
        );
    }
}
```

**mainpage.dart:** this view includes the drawer and its items

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'view1.dart';
import 'view2.dart';
import 'view3.dart';

/// just a wrapper class for drawer items; in my original code, these include 
/// icons and other properties
class DrawerItem {
    String title;
    DrawerItem({this.title});
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

    /// list of items in the drawer
    final drawerItems = [
        new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 1'),
        new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 2'), 
        new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 3')
    ];

    @override
    State<MainPage> createState() => new MainPageState();
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
    int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                /// dynamic title, depending on the current view
                title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedPageIndex].title),
            ),
            drawer: new Drawer(
                child: new ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new DrawerHeader(child: new Text('Drawer header')),
                        /// quick and easy way to create the items;
                        /// in the original
                        /// code, these items are built in a loop
                        _buildDrawerItem(0),
                        _buildDrawerItem(1),
                        _buildDrawerItem(2),
                    ],
                )
            ),
            body: _buildCurrentPage()
        );
    }

    Widget _buildCurrentPage() {
        switch(_selectedPageIndex) {
            case 0: return new View1();
            case 1: return new View2();
            case 2: return new View3();
        }
        return new Text('Invalid page index');
    }

    Widget _buildDrawerItem(int index) {
        return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[index].title),
            selected: _selectedPageIndex == index,
            onTap: () => _handleSelection(index),
        );
    }

    void _handleSelection(int index) {
        setState(() {
            _selectedPageIndex = index;
        });
        /// close the drawer
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }

}
```

This is the first root view:

**view1.dart:**

```
class View1 extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('Push Subview1'),
            onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                        return new SubView1();
                    }
                ));
            },
        );
    }

}
```

**subview1.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubView1 extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text('SubView1'),
            ),
            body: new Text('Pushed from View1')
        );
    }

}
```

I know about the Cupertino classes, but I prefer the material design. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Since they are two different pages, drawer in one page will not be available in another page. If you do want that you should create drawer in both pages. I've wrapped everything as much as i can regarding Drawer inside a separate class called `drawer.dart` with comments everywhere so that it would be helpful to understand.

***`Plugin used`***

`scoped_model: "^0.2.0"`

***`mainpage.dart`***

```
import 'package:commo_drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'view1.dart';
import 'view2.dart';
import 'view3.dart';

MainPageState mainPageState = new MainPageState();

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => mainPageState;
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  MyDrawer myDrawer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myDrawer =
        new MyDrawer(shouldRebuildState: DrawerItemClick.NEED_TO_REBUILD_STATE);
    myDrawer.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  rebuild() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(drawerItems[myDrawer.selectedPageIndex].title),
      ),
      drawer: myDrawer.buildDrawer(context),
      body: _buildCurrentPage(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCurrentPage() {
    switch (myDrawer.selectedPageIndex) {
      case 0:
        return new View1();
      case 1:
        return new View2();
      case 2:
        return new View3();
    }
    return new Text('Invalid page index');
  }
}
```

***`subview1.dart`***

```
import 'package:commo_drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SubView1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyDrawer myDrawer = new MyDrawer(shouldRebuildState: DrawerItemClick.NEED_NOT_REBUILD_STATE);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('SubView1'),
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }),
      ),
      body: new Text('Pushed from View1'),
      drawer: myDrawer.buildDrawer(context),
    );
  }
}
```

***`drawer.dart`***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
BuildContext _context;

class MyDrawer extends Model {
  DrawerItemClick shouldRebuildState;

  MyDrawer({this.shouldRebuildState});

  int get selectedPageIndex => _selectedPageIndex;

  Drawer buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;

    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          new DrawerHeader(child: new Text('Drawer header')),
          buildDrawerItem(0),
          buildDrawerItem(1),
          buildDrawerItem(2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildDrawerItem(int index) {
    return new ListTile(
      title: new Text(drawerItems[index].title),
      selected: selectedPageIndex == index,
      onTap: () => _handleSelection(index),
    );
  }

  void _handleSelection(int index) {
    Navigator.of(_context).pop(); // Close drawer
    if (shouldRebuildState == DrawerItemClick.NEED_TO_REBUILD_STATE) {
      if (_selectedPageIndex != index) {
        _selectedPageIndex = index;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } else {
      shouldRebuildState = DrawerItemClick.NEED_TO_REBUILD_STATE;
      Navigator.of(_context).pop(); // Close SubView

      if (_selectedPageIndex != index) {
        _selectedPageIndex = index;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }

  }
}

final drawerItems = [
  new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 1'),
  new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 2'),
  new DrawerItem(title: 'Item 3'),
];

class DrawerItem {
  String title;

  DrawerItem({this.title});
}

enum DrawerItemClick { NEED_TO_REBUILD_STATE, NEED_NOT_REBUILD_STATE }
```

Comment: Although this might be possible, it would require me to include the drawer (widget, items, selection handling, state handling) in _every_ subview of my app, unless I come up with something like a global drawer component that I can include in each. It doesn't "feel right".

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Hope it helps. Let me know if not.